# win32 select all on edit ctrl (textbox)

Tags: c++, user-interface, winapi, textbox

I am creating my textbox with these options. I can Copy / Cut / Paste / Undo, but when I hit **Select All** it doesn't select all. I can right click and click **Select All** but <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> doesn't do anything. Why?

```
wnd = CreateWindow("EDIT", 0,
    WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | ES_MULTILINE | WS_HSCROLL | WS_VSCROLL | ES_AUTOHSCROLL | ES_AUTOVSCROLL,
    x, y, w, h,
    parentWnd,
    NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tend to use MFC (forgive me) instead of Win32 so I cannot answer this definitively, but I noticed this comment added to a page on an MS site concerning talking with an Edit control (a simple editor within the Edit control):

> The edit control uses `WM_CHAR` for
> accepting characters, not `WM_KEYDOWN`
> etc. You must `Translate()` your
> messages or you ironically won't be
> able to edit the text in the edit
> control.

I don't know if this applies to BoltBait's response, but I suspect it does.

(I found this at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775462(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: wow thanks, i wanted to select all so i can copy text faster. That link showed me WM_COPY which copys the text needed. thanks!

Answer (score 6):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> is not a built-in accelerator like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.  This is why you see WM_CUT, WM_PASTE and WM_COPY messages defined, but there is no WM_SELECTALL.

You have to implement this functionality yourself.  I did in my MFC app like this:

```
static BOOL IsEdit( CWnd *pWnd ) 
{
    if ( ! pWnd ) return FALSE ;
    HWND hWnd = pWnd->GetSafeHwnd();
    if (hWnd == NULL)
     return FALSE;

    TCHAR szClassName[6];
    return ::GetClassName(hWnd, szClassName, 6) &&
         _tcsicmp(szClassName, _T("Edit")) == 0;
}

BOOL LogWindowDlg::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg) 
{
    if(pMsg->message==WM_KEYDOWN)
    {
        if ( pMsg->wParam=='A' && GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL)<0 )
        {
            // User pressed Ctrl-A.  Let's select-all
            CWnd * wnd = GetFocus() ;
            if ( wnd && IsEdit(wnd) )
                ((CEdit *)wnd)->SetSel(0,-1) ;
        }
    }   
    return CDialog::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}
```

Note, I stole IsEdit from this page:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/145616

I point that out partly because I want to give credit, and partly because I think the IsEdit function (comparing classname strings) is dorky and I want to give blame.

Comment: This code is from an MFC app.  I had to override the PreTranslateMessage function to make this happen in the MFC dialog class.  In a normal win32 message loop, you would perform this same task on each message you receive there, just before calling TranslateMessage.  But then you will need to translate the GetFocus and SetSel functions to their win32-api primitives.  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 6):

You could simply use EM_SETSEL message to the textbox,

According to MSDN ,

> If the start is 0 and the end is –1, all the text in the edit control is selected. If the start is –1, any current selection is deselected.

so,

```
SendMessage(hwndEdit,EM_SETSEL,0,-1);
```

Will work fine.

Answer (score 3):

You need to capture that keystroke and do the select all yourself.

Here is some C# code for use with a RichTextBox:

```
    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        // Ctrl-A does a Select All in the editor window
        if (e.Control && (e.KeyCode == Keys.A))
        {
            this.SelectAll();
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Sorry, I don't have Win32 code for you.

Comment: mine says "does not contain a defintion for "selectALL" and no extension method accepting an argument of a type could be found"

Comment: I too get the same error message as stated above. Where do I need to paste this snippet?

Answer (score 3):

The strange thing is that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> DOES work (as select all), if you do NOT specify ES_MULTILINE

But that doesn't help if you need multiline

The [MSDN documentation for ES_MULTILINE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775464%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) doesn't appear to say anything about this.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that something else is stealing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>? Use Spy++ to verify that it reaches your edit control.

Answer (score 0):

Why not add an accelerator for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> to `SelectAll`?

Comment: i guess i could but thats more code for me to write and learn how to do.
BTW i used WM_COPY instead which is what i wanted. To copy the text into the clipboard :)