# WinForms ReadOnly TextBox Ctrl-R key down

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a C# WinForms sample application, demonstrating interesting key handling issue.
That's very simple: there is just a `Form` and `TextBox` on it. I set `TextBox` `ReadOnly` property to `true`.

[image]

I have the next code in my `Form`:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyData.HasFlag(Keys.R))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There is 'R' key in KeyDown event");
        }
    }
}
```

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> keys, the `MessageBox` doesn't show up. But if I set `ReadOnly` property of `TextBox` to `true`, the `MessageBox` appears. The same thing happens, when I press <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> on `ReadOnly` `TextBox`.

[image]

Any ideas, what is special with `ReadOnly` `TextBox` and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> combination?

Comment: It also shows message box on `w`, `v`, `z`, `[`, `s`, `'`, `v`

Comment: @Shaharyar, I know, but that just demonstrates the issue. `if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.R)` doesn't work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a patch in the [TextBoxBase.ProcessCmdKey() method](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/ndp/fx/src/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/TextBoxBase.cs), it fixes a problem with certain short-cut keys still modifying the text when the control's ReadOnly property is set.  They are Ctrl+R, Ctrl+J, Ctrl+E and Ctrl+L.

Afaik, this patch is a bit too crude, it should only apply to RichTextBox.

This problem is fixable by overriding the TextBox class and restore the normal behavior of these keys.  Add a new class to your project and paste the code shown below.  Compile.  Drop the new control from the top of the toolbox, replacing your original textbox.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class MyTextBox : TextBox {
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData) {
        if (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.R) ||
            keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.L) ||
            keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.E) ||
            keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.J)) return false;
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
}
```

Comment: Small edit: I added a **ReadOnly** `&& keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.R)..` to that check

Comment: That isn't actually necessary, but ala.

Comment: This doesn't fix the issue for menu shortcuts, though, because they _should_ be handled by this.

Comment: The only workaround I found was to both use this replaced TextBox _and_ to catch KeyDown events on my textboxes, filtering out the calls whose source was a TextBox with ReadOnly set, and then calling the menu function for that specific key combination (Ctrl+E in my case).

Answer (score 1):

It appears this is a known issue.  You'd have to ask Microsoft for the why of it...
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/941c9759-5531-49fe-9ebb-7fc6d812b0fd/ctrle-not-working-in-a-read-only-text-box?forum=csharplanguage

General advice:  If you want to detect a specific *character*, then use `KeyPress()`.  It is called after translation from the keyboard key to the character set.

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(Object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == 'R')
        MessageBox.Show("Hit an 'R'");
}
```

To handle keyboard "shortcuts", change the test:

```
if (ModifierKeys == Keys.Control && e.KeyChar == 'R')
```

Comment: Thank you, that's a good point. But I need to handle keyboard shortcut. `KeyDown` fits more for that purpose.

Comment: Neither is better than the other, just suit the approach to the handler you choose.  Again, it comes down to wanting the physical keyboard key versus the _character_.

Answer (score 0):

You might look at the [ShortCutsEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.shortcutsenabled.aspx) property.

As already seen on this post: [Why are some textboxes not accepting Control + A shortcut to select all by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5885739/why-are-some-textboxes-not-accepting-control-a-shortcut-to-select-all-by-defau)

Comment: `ShortCutsEnabled` property didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

For CTRL+R combination

```
private void KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.R)
  {
    //your code
  }
}
```

Comment: This didn't help. Works for, let's say, Shift-R, but not Ctrl-R.

Comment: What do you mean? Of course the above code will work if the user press CTRL+R not Shift+R. If you want to include Shift you can use `e.Shift && e.KeyCode == Keys.R)`

Comment: I meant if you set the `TextBox` `ReadOnly = true`, `if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.R)` doesn't work for Ctrl-R, but `e.Shift && e.KeyCode == Keys.R)` works for Shift-R.

Comment: I see. The another option here is to transfer your KeyDown event in `Form_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)` and Set the form properties `KeyPreview = true`