# Tab button switches to wrong control in windows form application

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I am working in windows form application using c#. I have two fields in a form "Username" and "password" and two buttons "Login" and "Cancel". On form loading cursor is placed in Username textbox which is ok.

But when I press <kbd>TAB</kbd> from my keyboard instead of going to Password textbox its going to Login button. How can I set this?

Also the shortcut  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select all text is not working in text fields.
Any help?

Comment: You should set TabIndex right. It gives you the sequence of which tab is next when Tab button on keyboard is pressed. (Note*: It is in the comments cause it does not completely answer OPS whole question)

Comment: You need to adjust tab order for your controls: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/csz6b8x8.aspx

Comment: ok i set TabIndex to 2.... its working fine now :) Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every control on WinForms has a `TabIndex`. This you can find in the properties of the control. You need to adjust this value to 2 in the Password textbox if you want to have the focus switch there after <kbd>tab</kbd>

Select your control in the designer, go into the properties:

[image]

and set the TabIndex property:

[image]

The shortcut <kbd>Cntr</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> will only work if you have the focus on the `TextBox`! Also make sure that the `ShortCutsEnabled` property is set to true:

[image]

For reference here is the [original answer for the shortcut problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5893879/5174469). It says however that:

> The [TextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.aspx) control does not support the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> shortcut key when the [Multiline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12w624ff.aspx) property value is true.

Comment: yes, it resolved this.. thanks
and what about keyboard shortcuts like CTRL+A

Comment: @user3837889 not enough information about what you did so that this short cut does not work anymore.

Comment: @user3837889 it works only if you have the focus on the textbox. Did you override any of the key press or down events?#

Comment: @user3837889 please check the `ShortCutsEnabled` property of the textbox. I made an edit

Comment: yeah I just checked that and found that due to setting the multiline property to true CTRL+A is not working.

Answer (score 2):

Change the tabindex property of your password textbox 1 higher to the tabindex of your username textbox. (i.e. Username tabindex = 1, password tebaindex = 2)

Comment: yes, it resolved this.. thanks
and what about keyboard shortcuts like CTRL+A

Comment: If you are using Ctrl+A to select the text in textbox, that is already automatic.

Comment: resolved by giong through the link which Mong Zhu has shared. thank you

Answer (score 2):

The order of the 'tabs' is set by setting 'TabIndex'
eg.

```
controlName.TabIndex = 0;
```

Comment: yes, it resolved this.. thanks
and what about keyboard shortcuts like CTRL+A

Comment: That selects all text

Comment: yes it does... When I type in a username and I want to select it by pressing CTRL+A it doesn't work

Comment: resolved by giong through the link which Mong Zhu has shared. thank you

Answer (score 2):

Here is the answer to your second question regarding using Ctrl + A to select text in a TextBox.

To do this, you'll need to hook into the KeyDown event of the TextBox.
This is how you'd select the text:

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.A) // Select All
    {
        ((TextBox)sender).SelectAll();
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```